# Working with two dimensional arrays in JavaScript to detect repeated values

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been working on an example that detects repetitions by letter-number with the following JavaScript code.

But it's not working. The idea is that it detects that the combination A-1 is repeated; using a control matrix.

This is the items JSON structure:

```
{
letter: 'A',
number: '1',
},
{
letter: 'B',
number: '2',
},
{
letter: 'A',
number: '1',
},
{
letter: 'C',
number: '2',
},
```

And this is the code I am trying to:

```
var isRepeated = false;
var numItems = items.length;
if (numItems > 0) {
    var item; 
    var letter;
    var number;
    var matrix = [[]];
    for (var j = 0; j < numItems; j++) {
        item = items[j];
        letter = item.letter;
        number = item.number;
        if (matrix[letter][number] == undefined) {
            matrix[letter][number] = true;
        } else {
            isRepeated = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
matrix[letter][number]
```

You're trying to access elements of an array using string keys but arrays use integer indexes

Here's an alternative if you just want to know if something is repeated

```js
const props = [{
    letter: 'A',
    number: '1',
  },
  {
    letter: 'B',
    number: '2',
  },
  {
    letter: 'A',
    number: '1',
  },
  {
    letter: 'C',
    number: '2',
  },
]

const didRepeat = (array) => array.some(((hash) => ({letter, number}) => {
  const key = `${letter}_${number}`;

  if (hash.has(key)) return true;
  return hash.add(key), false;
})(new Set()))

console.log(didRepeat(props))
```

Comment: Great code handling!